# Can someone clear up static variables for me?

Tags: php, variables, static

Using PHP here, I decided to read through the manual chapter by chapter and learn new things. So now I've discovered static variables, which seem like an awesome concept, but the way I understand it is:

Static variables are set once and only once per load of the script. They can be changed and incremented but not actually re-set. Usually used in functions to set a value and not have to initialize that variable every time the function runs.

```
<?php

function count2( $inputNum ) {
    static $a = $inputNum;
    echo $a++; //Echo and then increment.
}

for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    count2(50);
}

?>
```

I'd expect this to start the static `$a` var at 50, and increment 11 times. How come I get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static variable cannot be initialized with another variable, whose value is not known until runtime.  You must initialize it with a value known at compile time.

```
function count2($inputNum) {
  // Initialize only once to an integer (non variable, non-expression)
  static $a = 0;
  if ($a === 0) {
    // If $a is still 0, set it to $inputNum
    $a = $inputNum;
  }
  echo $a++;
}

// First run outputs 25
count2(25);
// 25
// Subsequent runs increment
count2(25);
// 26
count2(25);
// 27
```

[Relevant documentation...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: Hey thanks, so let me see if I got this right. You set the static to a dummy value (0) just to tell it it's static, and then when you change it to the parameter it still keeps it's static state so it doesn't reinitialize itself?

Comment: @user1159454 yes it keeps it, the next time the function is called the line will `static $a = 0` won't take effect

Comment: @user1159454 Yes that is correct.  The `static` initialization will only happen once and the function will retain the value on subsequent calls.  The `$a++` increments it (after returning and echoing).

Answer (score 4):

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties **may only be initialized using a literal or constant**; expressions are not allowed.
>   So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array
>   (for instance), **you may not initialize it to another variable**, to a
>   function return value, or to an object.

I think you missed that part from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) (emphasize mine) :)

Comment: Ah yes I did miss that. That manual is hard for me, it keeps talking about concepts it probably expects me to already know, and then introduces that concept like 3 pages later..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Few problems off the bat:

- You can only declare a static var once. Your syntax clobbers it over and over by calling `count2()` 10 times.
- You can't use the `++` operator because you can't change a static var
- Not using define and [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)

Perhaps try something like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* setup */

function set( $input ) {
    define( 'A', $input );
}
function tick() {
    echo constant( 'A' ) . "\n";
}

/* run */

set( 50 );
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    tick();
}

?>
```

This will output:

```
$ php test.php 
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
50
```

Comment: In the example I based this off from the docs they did that (increment). Also it works if I initialize the static var with a number

Comment: Hmmm, I tested and this works: `$ php -r 'static $a = 3; $a++; echo $a;'`